# Saving and loading eclipse uml2 model

Tags: java, eclipse, uml

I want to save and load eclipse uml2 model programmatically but I cant find method that would help me in this. Any ideas how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I just google it and you should take a look at http://wiki.eclipse.org/MDT/UML2/FAQ .

Hoping it helps,

EBR